# QTP, Is there anyway to make changes to all function libraries at once ?

Tags: function, qtp

is there anyway in QTP to make changes take place on all function libraries at once without having to go to each function library and make the update ?

i have an issue with some functions, i have built new ones and i want to use them in my script.

your help is highly appreciated.

thanks 
Manaysah

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, in QTP there is no such way to update code present in multiple tab whatever it may be function library , action or reusable in multiple tabs. You have to proceed manually. You can use some advance Editor like [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/). But again you can make changes only in code & not in OR. It is easy to such task for datatable as it can be directly open as excel file.

If you want to update only code, then you can open required function libraries in notepad++.Then Go to Search - Replace (Ctrl + H)& then Click on Replace all in all open documents.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks very much ....this is much helpful 
i know this way using notepad++ but i hadnt used it before.